# Android ContentObsrver for single row change

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I would like to write a `ContentObserver` for my app's local table. Also I have `ContentProvider` to access the table. Now in one of my Activity i have to observe for a change in only one row of that table. I have the primary key to observe for it but the primary key is a `TEXT` not `INTEGER`. When googled on it I found about getting specific row's `Uri` by using [ContentUris.withAppendedId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html#withAppendedId%28android.net.Uri,%20long%29) method. But it requires id must be `long(NUMBER)`. So is there a way I can get `Uri` of single row of a table when the id is `TEXT`?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#withAppendedPath(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String)

Comment: will that uri point to the row which has the primary key value as the String value i pass?

Comment: Content providers require _id column to refer to rows (or work properly). You should create _id column and set it to auto-increment. Now you can use either _id or URI to filter rows. Have a look here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Comment: @Ram Uri can point to anything you want,  its just your imagination how you could map Uri parts into your data model

Comment: @Ayub no, there is no need to have _id column in content provider

Comment: @pskink so in my content provider I already have the base URI along with 7 other table's uris with URI matcher. So how should I implement to receive the dynamically created Uri in my content provider class?

Comment: what is a difference if its INT or STRING?

Comment: @pskink I understand this will work if I just call the my content provider with the generated uri. Will try it and let you know...

Comment: @pskink I tried adding a new Uri matcher in my content provider with "/#" at the end for it. But the matcher returns the uri value only when i pass the integer value. When i pass a String to it, it return '-1' :(

Comment: I found it was my mistake to use /* for Strings from the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html#addURI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: @Ram so the lesson is: always read the documentation before any coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments of @pskink I found the way to achieve it and would like to share it. In the existing content provider's uri matcher we have to add '/*' with new entry as follows...

```
private static final String AUTH = "com.test.Provider";

public static final Uri TABLE_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTH + "/"
        + TABLE_NAME);
public static final Uri TABLE_ID_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTH
        + "/" + TABLE_NAME + "/*");

final static int TABLE_COMMENT = 10;
final static int TABLE_ROW_COMMENT = 11;

uriMatcher.addURI(AUTH, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COMMENT);
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTH, TABLE_NAME + "/*", TABLE_ROW_COMMENT);
```

And in the query method as follows...

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String orderBy) {
db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = null;

switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
 case TABLE_COMMENT:
     cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, selection,selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
     if (cursor != null)
     cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
     break;

case TABLE_ROW_COMMENT:
    String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();//getting the PK
    cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projection,Table._ID + "=?", new String[] { id },null, null, orderBy);
    if (cursor != null)
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
    break;
    }
 return cursor;
}
```

And from the activity or fragment can get a specific row's uri from the loader as follows...

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Provider.TABLE_URI,
            "pk value");
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,
                null);
```

And in my case I'll use this Uri for Observer.